# How to do perform a performance testing, keycloak enable web application

Tags: jmeter, keycloak

**i need example for this.can anyone to do demonstrate it.with all steps.** i try to lot of methods.but any methods not work properly.
[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQtXl.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot **do demonstrate it.with all steps** looking into single screenshot with View Results Tree listener limited output.

Moreover, keycloak can be configured differently hence "all steps" may be different for [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) and [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)

In general you need to [correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) dynamic parameters like `execution`, `tab_id`, `session_code`, etc. using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) like [Regular Expression Extractor or Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/), store them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace recorded values with the JMeter Variables.

Example dynamic parameters detection:

[image]

And handling:

[image]

Comment: The animated Gif can be opened in Preview on Mac os which lets you see the individual frames.  frame 21 for app request, frame 30 for keycloak login form request, frame 64 for session code extractor, frame 72 for execution, frame 76 for tab id.  Frame 82 has the submit login form request.