# Testing keycloak login/registration using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, keycloak

We have an requirement to test Keycloak Login/Registration using Keycloak application. When I open portal and click on continue to Login/Registration, it is redirecting to the following URL and taking Query Parameter.

I am not aware how and from which section we can get the value of Query parameter to pass

https://keycloak.*****.com/realms/***/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=***&redirect_uri=http****personal-information

state= f707ae75-4543-46a8-8204-538492251966

nonce= 03d80815-c174-4453-83d4-0324726b87df

code challenge= OpSGM55wKbL4suTi_-FJcyWIdD63UryMV8fX4Mu-dc4

code challenge method= S256

tab id= ub4Sj_h_Cho

Please help here, if possible
Thanks

Comment: just for loggin:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71083327/how-to-do-perform-a-performance-testing-keycloak-enable-web-application

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned you're **redirected** which means that one of the previous request responds with i.e. [302 HTTP Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) and its [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header contains the keycloak URL and all these query parameters.

If you need to extract them for future use - go for [Regular Expression Extractor or Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor), just make sure to choose the relevant "Field to check"

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. Sorry to use redirection word here, This is Portal URL which, There is an Start button present to click and navigate to Keycloak page to register Users. This Start Click use Dynamic Form Parameters. These dynamic parameter I am not getting on Portal Home Page, This is using PKCE

Answer (score 0):

Your app uses `Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)`, so you need to understand:

1.) OIDC auth request (`client_id,redirect_uri,state` parameters - they configured in your IDP/Keyclok usually): https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest

2.) PKCE part (`code_challenge,code_challenge` parameters - they are generated usually): https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636

Comment: Thanks @Jan Garaj for your comments, Yes Application is using PKCE mechanism. I am looking and trying to get these information,